# Add a solid bar to the side of an environment

Tags: align, environments

I'm writing a paper, and much of it is quite encylopaedic (i.e., it has definition after definition after definition...)

To make it a bit clearer where definitions and exposition start/end, **I want my definitions to appear with a solid-colored rectangle to appear to the left of them.** I've edited a screenshot of a definition from my current document to illustrate what I'm going for. If it matters, I'm using the `amsart` document class.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically you need  a `minipage` with a `\vrule` ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\newenvironment{yetotherdef}%
{\bigskip\par\noindent\vrule width 1em\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}\paragraph{Definition.}}
{\end{minipage}\bigskip\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begin{yetotherdef}
    \lipsum[2][1-6]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[3][1]
        \item \lipsum[4][1]
    \end{itemize}   
    \lipsum[5][1-6]
\end{yetotherdef}

\begin{yetotherdef}
    \lipsum[6][1-2]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[7][1]
        \item \lipsum[8][1]
    \end{itemize}   
\end{yetotherdef}

\lipsum[9][1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

But take a look also to the `tcolorbox`  manual.